# Have UIImage fill the whole frame of the UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a small game project, and i have created an image that is 25 x 35 Width / height. Now, if i create a UIImageView with a frame that exactly matches the image, and set the image of that object to the image named above, i thought it would fill it all, but it doesn't, not even by a long shot. It's like there is this huge rectangle, and the image is just added in the middle, so it only fills like 50% of it? any way i can make the image fit exactly?

I tried making the background with a UIColorWithPatternImage, but still doesn't work.

Thanks on advance
/JBJ

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = frame;
[imageView sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a 25x35 image and 25x35 UIImageview everything must be ok.
Please post some line of code.
If you want to make a game have considered engine like cocos2d? (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.image = image;
imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
```